# Salesforce: Upload Apex Trigger via Java

Tags: java, salesforce, apex, sfdc

I want to upload an ApexTrigger to Salesforce via Java so that my available options as far as I know are either:

- Upload via REST
- Upload via SOAP
- Upload via pre-defined/created Maven artifact library

For authentication i have the option to either use the *OAuth token* returned from Salesforce while logging on to the *REST API* or *username, password, security token, client id, client secret*, while the first approach to reuse the REST API token would be my favorite one.

**None of my actual attempts worked yet and my question is obviously how to get it working or where my mistake is.**

I've tried the following:

- Upload via *Metadata API* `createMetadata()`

  - developer.salesforce.com: Metadata API Developer Guide | CRUD-Based Metadata Development
- Upload via *Tooling API* `POST /sobjects/SObjectName/`

  - developer.salesforce.com Tooling API | REST Resources

### Metadata API approach

I started with the *Metadata API* approach:

```java
@Test
    void testTriggerUploadMetadataApi() {
        String username = "REDACTED";
        String password = "REDACTED";
        String securityToken = "REDACTED";
        String url = "https://REDACTEDDOMAIN.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap";
        String authPrefix = "/u";
        String servicePrefix = "/m";
        String version = "/60.0";


        LoginResponse loginResponse = this.authController
                .authLoginPost(new Login("REDACTED", "REDACTED").thirdPartyConfig(thirdPartyConfig))
                .block();
        assertNotNull(loginResponse);
        // Session is here a wrapper for the actual REST API OAuth Token with additional metadata
        Session session =
                assertDoesNotThrow(() -> new ObjectMapper().readValue(loginResponse.getToken(), Session.class));

        ConnectorConfig connectorConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
        connectorConfig.setUsername(username);
        connectorConfig.setPassword(password + securityToken);
        connectorConfig.setAuthEndpoint("https://login.salesforce.com/service/Soap" + authPrefix + version);
        connectorConfig.setServiceEndpoint(url + servicePrefix + version);
        connectorConfig.setProxy("REDACTED", 8080);
        Transport transport = new JdkHttpTransport(connectorConfig);
        connectorConfig.setTransport(transport.getClass());

        MetadataConnection metadataConnection = assertDoesNotThrow(() -> new MetadataConnection(connectorConfig));
        metadataConnection.setSessionHeader(session.getBearerTokenString());

        ApexTrigger apexTrigger = new ApexTrigger();
        apexTrigger.setFullName("SomeTrigger");
        apexTrigger.setStatus(ApexCodeUnitStatus.Active);
        apexTrigger.setApiVersion(56.0);
        apexTrigger.setContent(
                "trigger SomeTrigger on Account(after insert, after update {}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> metadataConnection.upsertMetadata(new Metadata[] {apexTrigger}));
    }
```

Which resulted in:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception thrown: com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException: INVALID_TYPE: This type of object is not available for this organization
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.createAssertionFailedError(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.assertDoesNotThrow(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:75)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.assertDoesNotThrow(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:58)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(Assertions.java:3228)
    at redacted.package.name.SFLoginTest.testTriggerUploadMetadataApi(SFLoginTest.java:139)
```

I then started to research a little and found [the following trailblazer thread](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/de/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4QRvSAN) where in the comments *Daniel Ballinger from Salesforce* states that it's probably impossible since *"This metadata type is not supported by the create(), delete(), and update() calls.
While not explicit, this also applies to the createMetadata() method, which create() was depricated to."*

He also states *"Instead you can use the Metadata API deploy method, or the Tooling API to create the Apex Class."* so that i researched further where i found this [trailblazer thread](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/de/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T42ECSAZ) where *Sunad Rasane* states that he used the *Tooling API* instead with a link to this [stackexchange thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301169/system-calloutexception-invalid-type-this-type-of-object-is-not-available-for/301170%E2%8C%97301170) where an example for a trigger upload via *Tooling API* was already present so that I opted for using the *Tooling API* since it looked convenient to use:

### Tooling API approach

```java
@Test
    void testTriggerUploadToolingApi() {

        Map<String, Object> thirdPartyConfig = getThirdPartyConfig();

        LoginResponse loginResponse = this.authController
                .authLoginPost(new Login("REDACTED", "REDACTED").thirdPartyConfig(thirdPartyConfig))
                .block();
        assertNotNull(loginResponse);
        // Session is here a wrapper for the actual REST API OAuth Token with additional metadata
        Session session =
                assertDoesNotThrow(() -> new ObjectMapper().readValue(loginResponse.getToken(), Session.class));
        String url = session.getBaseUrl() + "/services/data/" + session.getApiVersion() + "/sobjects/ApexTrigger";
        System.out.println("Request URL: [" + url + "]");

        Map<String, String> apexTrigger = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        apexTrigger.put("Name", "UploadTest_AccountTrigger");
        apexTrigger.put("TableEnumOrId", "Account");
        apexTrigger.put(
                "Body",
                assertDoesNotThrow(() -> Files.readString(
                        Path.of("src/test/resources/salesforce/apex/SimpleAccountTriggerExpected.txt"))));

        String requestBody = assertDoesNotThrow(() -> new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(apexTrigger));
        System.out.println("Request body: [" + requestBody + "]");

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("REDACTED", 8080)))
                .connectTimeout(Duration.of(60, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                .build();
        HttpRequest uploadRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .timeout(Duration.of(60, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .header("Authorization", "OAuth " + session.getBearerTokenString())
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response =
                assertDoesNotThrow(() -> httpClient.send(uploadRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()));
        System.out.println("Status Code: [" + response.statusCode()+ "]");
        System.out.println("Body: [" + response.body() + "]");
        
        assertTrue(String.valueOf(response.statusCode()).startsWith("2"));
    }
```

Which results in:

```
Expected :true
Actual   :false
<Click to see difference>

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.failNotTrue(AssertTrue.java:63)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:36)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(Assertions.java:183)
    at redacted.package.nameSFLoginTest.testTriggerUploadToolingApi(SFLoginTest.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension$2.proceed(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:142)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.interceptEach(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:157)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.interceptTest(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:114)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.interceptTestMethod(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

With the following output on STDOUT:

```
Request URL: [https://REDACTEDDOMAIN.my.salesforce.com/services/data/56.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger]
Request body: [{"Name":"UploadTest_AccountTrigger","TableEnumOrId":"Account","Body":"trigger Account_AccountWebhook on Account (after insert, after update) {}"}]
Status Code: [404]
Body: [[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after the depressing finding that the "v" prefix for the version is missing the *Tooling API* approaches base URL it works now as described.

Below you can find the correct way to build the request URL (replace this in the *Tooling API Approach*:

```java
String url = session.getBaseUrl() + "/services/data/v" + session.getApiVersion() + "/sobjects/ApexTrigger";
```