# Salesforce SOAP API: Where do I get the EnterpriseConnection class from?

Tags: java, salesforce, apex, sfdc, sfdc-metadata-api

I need to upload an ApexTrigger via API to Salesforce ([See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78185349/salesforce-upload-apex-trigger-via-java)).

Since some of the examples are using the SOAP API with the `EnterpriseConnection` class in wanted to follow those examples.

The problem is, I don't find this class. So my question in what Maven artifact or WSDL is this class contained in?

I am using the following gradle dependencies in my project:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation("com.force.api:force-apex-api:60.1.1")
    implementation("com.force.api:force-metadata-api:60.1.1")
    implementation("com.force.api:force-partner-api:60.1.1")
    implementation("com.force.api:force-tooling-api:32.0.0")
    implementation("com.force.api:force-wsc:60.1.1")
    // ...
}
```

and i have had a look under *Setup -> Integrations -> API*

- Enterprise WSDL
- Partner WSDL
- Apex WSDL
- Metadata WSDL
- Tooling WSDL
- Delegated Authentication WSDL
- Client Certificate

where none of them contains a class called `Enterprise API`.

Soooooooo, where to find it?